# How to find the series cardinality of a single measurement in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, cardinality, influxql

With InfluxQL, the following query shows you the overall **series cardinality** of the database.

```
SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY
```

How can I see the series cardinality of a single measurement? Or even better, all the measurements in a database with their respective cardinalities, as a list?

I am using InfluxDB 1.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't expecting it to be that simple but it turns out the query below works.

```
SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY FROM <some_measurement_name>
```